# Windows Automatic naming from info in PDF file itself

Tags: python, batch-file, pdf, batch-rename

I am trying to find out a way to take scanned pdfs that are automatically named things like "397009900" to a certain string inside the PDF itself. In my case it is a drawing name that I am trying to extract from the PDF to rename the file ie "ISO-4024-4301".

Is there a way to automatically rename a PDF file with information from inside of it?

Thanks very much.

Comment: A pdf is not a plain text file, whilst in some cases the text you require may still be readable as text, I wouldn't advise trying to read those files using a batch file. Use a scripting language or utility which understands the pdf format instead. _Please also note that requests for recommendations of software/utilities are off topic here._

Comment: ahh okay that makes sense, and  thanks I did not know that. I will remove that line :)

Comment: If they are *"scanned"* PDFs there won't be any string-like information in them at all - they will be purely images, so you'll actually have a picture of the word "ISO-4024...". That would mean you would need OCR.

Comment: Given that you say it is a scanned PDF, you would need to look into a software that can perform OCR, and perhaps also a Batch processing function, where by you setup a job in said program to open each PDF, perform OCR to extract the naming information you desire, then re-save the file with the new name. As Compo said, we cant make any recommendation on which one to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with python.

```
import PyPDF2
with open('path_to_file\Test doc.pdf', 'rb') as p:
    pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(p)
    pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)
    info=pageObj.extractText()
    print(info)
```

You can specify the page number where you want to extract the information. Change page number from 0 where you want to extract.

```
pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)
```

The extracted texts will be stored in the variable `info`, then you can perform any operation to choose the required text you want to rename to.

```
import os
os.rename(r'old_file_path_and_name_with_extension',r'new_file_path_and_name_with_extension')
```

With OS module, you can easily rename the files!